# syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: sql, bash

I have an SQL query that when it is put in to a function it stops working with this `syntax error: unexpected end of file` error message. Removing it from a function causes it to start working again.

Why is this?

```
function pull_data
{
    sqlplus -s $user/$pass@$db << EOF
    SELECT DISTINCT order_number,
                    order_total_items,
                    order_total_value
    FROM orders

    WHERE order_date BETWEEN '$1' AND '$2';

    exit;

    EOF
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The indented heredoc delimiter breaks it.  Say:

```
EOF
```

instead of

```
    EOF
```

Comment: Another option is the `<<-` operator, but it does impose the restriction that you use tabs to indent the code: "If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters are
       stripped from input lines and  the  line  containing  delimiter.   This
       allows  here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural
       fashion."