# Error in creating p4 label non-interactively as part of shell script

Tags: shell, sh, perforce

Here is the code snippet for creating a p4 label in my shell script

```
for i in $( echo TEST-01); do
    p4 label -i << ENDOFLABEL
    Label: $i
    Options: unlocked

    Description: label from Automation

    View:
         //depot/...

    ENDOFLABEL
done
```

It throws error as below; what is wrong?

```
warning: here-document at line 125 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `ENDOFLABEL')
./p4_l.sh: line 150: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [syntax error: unexpected end of file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282533/syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end marker of the here document must be left justified.

```
for i in $( echo TEST-01); do
    p4 label -i << ENDOFLABEL
    Label: $i
    Options: unlocked

    Description: label from Automation

    View:
         //depot/...

ENDOFLABEL
done
```

Or, if you use actual tabs for indentation, you can use a minus sign in front of the start label:

```
for i in $( echo TEST-01); do
    p4 label -i <<-ENDOFLABEL
    Label: $i
    Options: unlocked

    Description: label from Automation

    View:
         //depot/...

    ENDOFLABEL
done
```

Spaces won't work.  All leading tabs from the here document will be removed.  This fixes the problem with `p4` not liking spaces before lines such the `Label:` line.  There are other ways to handle such problems.  One is to use a letter such as `X` to mark where the 'real data' starts:

```
    sed 's/^[[:space:]]*X//' <<-ENDOFLABEL | p4 label -i
    XLabel: $i
    XOptions: unlocked

    XDescription: label from Automation

    XView:
    X     //depot/...

    ENDOFLABEL
done
```

Only the ENDOFLABEL line *must* be tab-indented, and you can have tabs before the `//depot/` line if you need them.

Comment: it helped, thanks, but after this it throws error as "Too many entries for field 'Label'." any clue? thanks again.

Comment: At that point, you're into debugging `p4` itself.  Maybe you need a blank line after the `Label:` line?

Comment: don't mind, I sorted it out, a space in front of Options: was the issue. Thanks.